# How to avoid "Loading..." message/ flash in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, memoization, custom-function

Is there a way to disable the `Loading...` message that appears in Google Sheets when calculations are being made?

If there's not a way to disable it, is there a way to *trick* it? In other words, let the calculations be determined in a hidden row and `import` them into a cell when finished?

The reason the `Loading...` is taking so long is due to a custom script that does a `=count` on every cell specified within the range when a change has been made to a cells **background color**.

```
.                                
.                             <color>      <range>   <key>  <range> ← (auto refresh cell)              
.                                ▼            ▼        ▼       ▼
=countWhereBackgroundColorIs("#e9f7fe", "$G175:$BN264","",$G175:$BN264)
.
.
.
```

It's super handy, but w/ this comes the performance hit.

Anyone have any pointers?

---

**Here's a video of the problem in action:** [Google Sheets "Loading..." problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByR1kQvOUDJbWkFqUTlEWl9hakk/view)

[image: Disable Google Sheets "Loading..." message]

Comment: Asynchronous custom functions. Hmm that's something interesting to look into. This is normally not possible, so like you pointed out there will have to be a work around.

Comment: I assume the intent is that no message is returned and the cells appear blank until the correct value is displayed.

Comment: Yes @SpencerEaston , that's the idea. I was looking for a way to *"silently"* do the math in the background..and when it finishes, update everything at once w/ the correct values so the user has a more friendly UI/UX experience. In its current form, the spreadsheet shows `Loading...` messages in multiple places every time a cell is edited (very distracting). In web development, this term is called **"FOUJ"**, or, *Flash Of Uninitialized Javascript*.

Comment: I've actually came up w/ a solution that fixes my particular use case..About to post my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *trick* with this is to hide all the calculations and use `=IMPORTRANGE` to bring in the totals. That way users will never see millions of **"Loading..."** flashes, they will just see the cell update when it's ready.

So it's simple as...

1. Run your functions and get the results
2. Hide row that your results are in
3. Import the result where you want it w/ `=IMPORTRANGE`

```
    =IMPORTRANGE("<spreadsheet_key>" , "<sheet> ! <cell>")
```

---

**Here's a quick video showing the result:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByR1kQvOUDJbVGlpdmd2dVBDM0k/view