# How to hide Loading... in custom formulas created in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling, sleep

I have a simple formula I wrote in Google Apps Script so I can implement the SLEEP function in my sheet. The script is:

```
function DELAY(formula,seconds) {
Utilities.sleep((seconds*1000))  
return formula
}
```

My problem is when I use the function in my sheets, the cell value will say Loading... until the sleep function is finished. I know I could always use IFERROR but it would be much more convenient to implement it into the script. Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid "Loading..." message/ flash in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691646/how-to-avoid-loading-message-flash-in-google-sheets)

Comment: this sounds like an xy probelem where you're trying to scrape data from the internet and have decided that this "DELAY()" function will help you do it without grinding the sheet and hitting quotas.

Comment: Google Sheets is probably working as intended. It is unclear why you would need to sleep in a custom function. If you are trying to avoid collisions, use the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) instead. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The reason I need to clear it is because there are functions that I want to change after a certain time. So, I need an ifferror. I can use the IFERROR but I wanted to implement it.

Comment: @MattKing Scraping the internet has nothing to do with the DELAY function I built nor did I ever mention anything about scraping. I asked for how to implement IFERROR in Google Apps Script. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> it would be much more convenient to implement it into the script

Currently, There's no way to implement such a feature in Google apps script.